# Looping through os.walk() confusion

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I'm  working on a script that will crawl a hard drive and collect information on each file
it encounters by way of fnmatch and magic.

I have a feeling that the first nested for-loop in `yield_files(root)` are unnecessary

```
def yield_files(root):
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        """ Is this necessary 

        for directory in dirs:
            for filename in directory:
                filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.isdir(filename):
                    yield FileInfo(filename)
        """

        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.isdir(filename):            
                yield FileInfo(filename)
```

Would `os.walk()` end-up recursing into these directories anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def yield_files(root):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            filename = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(filename) or os.path.isdir(filename):            
                yield FileInfo(filename)
```

That's all you need. The rest is indeed unnecessary. `os.walk` goes into subdirectories so you don't need the current directory's path, you just need `root` as the base for the path join as you've done.