# Split large directory into chunks of files

Tags: python, tarfile

I have a directory structure with a lot of files in it (~1 million) which I would like to zip into chunks of 10k files. So far I have this, which creates, well, garbage files-- when I unzip them it looks like all of the files are glommed into one long file instead of individual files--- and I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    dirctr = 1
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.input_dir, followlinks=False):
        counter = 1
        curtar= args.output_dir + 'File' + str(dirctr) + '.gz'
        tar = tarfile.open(name=curtar, mode="w:gz")
        for filename in files:
            if ((counter -1) % args.files_per_dir) == 0:
                if tarfile.is_tarfile(curtar):
                    tar.close(curtar)
                dirctr = dirctr + 1
                curtar= args.output_dir + 'File' + str(dirctr) + '.gz'
                
                tar.open(name=curtar, mode="w:gz")
            tar.add(os.path.join(root,filename))
            counter = counter + 1
    tar.close(curtar)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're say about make 3 zips off the first directory and 10 off the second, but it seems to me like you could just iterate though the files `os.walk` produces and after every 10k or whatever of them have been seen do whatever it is you want to do them.

Comment: I have 1M files, spread over (let's say) 15 directories. Some have more files than others. I would like to keep some of that structure, putting all of the files in a single directory in groups of 10k (or less if I can't make a full 10k out of the remaining files in that particular directory). What I need are .gz files containing those chunks. Right now this will give me a garbage .gz file after it iterates through 10k files. I have a version of this script which will copy 10k files at a time to a new directory but I need something that will zip those files.

Comment: What does "keep some of that structure" mean? What I described doesn't care what you do with the files, it's just a way to create groups of them for processing (creating tar files of them or whatever). The groups may contain files from any number of directories.

Comment: If directory 1 has 12300 files there should be 2 .gz files. One with 10000 files and one with 2300 files. Then it moves to directory 2  and creates another .gz file for each group of 10k files in that directory, and so forth.

Comment: If you used [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to iteratively traverse the folder hierarchy, it would be relatively easy to watch for directory changes and do something like that (in addition to limiting the total number from any one folder). See the answer to [Looping through os.walk() confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399626/looping-through-os-walk-confusion) for a simple way to use it iteratively to allow doing this.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the last comment. Grouping the files is not my issue. It's putting them in the .gz files that is.

Comment: Grouping them in groups of a limited size as well as by what folder they're in *is most definitely* a part of the processing required to do what you want. Using `os.walk` as suggested would make doing both of them at the same time relatively easy to accomplish. But if you disagree, you'll have to use one of the other suggestions or answers your question has gotten.

Comment: I don't disagree to the point that it's right there in the original code snippet. I'm using `os.walk`. Not the problem. The problem is that the .gz files I'm generating are garbage.

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information than saying they're "garbage"? When asking questions here it usually best to provide a [mre] (MRE) with only enough code in it to allow the problem to be reproduced (and ultimately solved). If grouping isn't the problem, the get rid of the code doing it so we're not distracted by it.

Comment: Hopefully this is more clear-- sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, that looks helpful, esp the description of what's wrong with files produced — I'll see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're *not* using `os.walk()` and doing the grouping correctly. Your code opens the same tar file multiple times and either adds no files to it or adds different ones each time — no wonder they're "garbage". It also never closes them when it should (except the last one at the very end). You can see what it's doing by adding print statements at all the appropriate places so you can trace its execution.